# Is satisfying the secant property a sufficient condition for cyclicity of a quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

You have a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ with diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ meeting at $P$.

If $PA \cdot PC = PB \cdot PD$, does this necessarily imply $ABCD$ is cyclic? I was unable to find any statement of the sort online and would appreciate any answer proving or disproving this.

Comment: See the [Intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem)

Comment: @user376343 This was not the question, as far as I understand it though your answer may help in the direction to a solution. Based on the theorem, attempt to build a case that is not, and you will find the answer.

Comment: @Moti the converse is true as well, it is written in the cited Wikipedia article, below the proof the mentioned theorem.

Comment: You need to prove it.

Comment: @user376343 thanks, somehow missed that. But the article doesn't seem to prove it.